# How do `stat` and `file` differentiate symlinks?

Tags: terminal, symlink

I was doing my routine work today and it seems the `stat` and `file` commands in the terminal don‘t show if a file is a symbolic link:

```
flow2k@myPad:dir ln -s aa.iml superlink
flow2k@myPad:dir stat superlink
16777220 11057327 lrwxr-xr-x 1 flow2k staff 0 6 "Dec  2 13:25:34 2017" "Dec  2 13:25:34 2017" "Dec  2 13:25:34 2017" "Dec  2 13:25:34 2017" 4096 8 0 superlink
```

How can I see whether something is a symlink?

Comment: What kind of output would you expect to show it is a symlink?

Comment: @patrix Being somewhat accustomed to Linux, I expected the string "symbolic link" to be explicitly shown in the output, like the samples shown here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49326/227169

Comment: Well, macOS ain‘t Linux :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `l` in `lrwxr-xr-x` shows that is is a (symbolic) link.
Use `readlink file` to show where the symbolic link points to.

The [`stat` manual page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) states:

> When invoked as **readlink**, only the target of the symbolic link is printed.  If the given argument is not a symbolic link, **readlink** will print nothing and exit with an error.

Answer (score 2):

BSD `stat` and `file` differ from their Linux counterparts but the BSD versions can mimic the Linux output. From the manual for `file`:

```
-h, --no-dereference
         option causes symlinks not to be followed (on systems that support symbolic links).

file -h /etc
/etc: symbolic link to private/etc
```

and from the manual for `stat`

```
 -x      Display information in a more verbose way as known from some Linux distributions.

stat -x /etc
File: "/etc"
Size: 11           FileType: Symbolic Link
Mode: (0755/lrwxr-xr-x)         Uid: (    0/    root)  Gid: (    0/   wheel)
Device: 1,4   Inode: 419701    Links: 1
Access: Sun Apr 16 14:39:45 2017
Modify: Sun Apr 16 14:39:45 2017
Change: Sun Apr 16 14:41:19 2017
```